# Is bandwidth of cmos comparator important?

Tags: mosfet, cmos, comparator, bandwidth

The concept of bandwidth is developed based on small-signal analysis. However, comparator works usually under large-signal conditions, and transistors are not in saturation region, since comparator works in open loop. So why do we care about bandwidth of comparator? Isn't slew rate the right thing to look at for characterizing comparator's speed?

Comment: Both are important. For small input overdrive you still want the comparator response time to be fast.

Comment: If input overdrive happens, the comparator enters a large-signal mode of operation right? Do you mean the comparator needs to be fast when overdrive is not happening? @Brian Drummond

Comment: *and transistors are not in saturation region* I've designed comparators that keeps most of the MOSFETs in the saturation region so that the comparator can be **faster**. Small signal analysis for a comparator is sometimes relevant **at the tripping point** so where it changes state. Most comparators' speed is indeed limited by **slewing**. That does not mean that small signal bandwidth can be ignored.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Are the two of you are using 'saturation' in the same sense, as it's a different region for BJTs and MOSFETs?

Comment: I am referring to the saturation region of MOSFET @Neil_UK.

Comment: If bandwidth is important, and gain of comparator is also important, there is a trade of between them. How can I know how large should the bandwidth of comparator be? For opamp I have specification about bandwidth for opamp. What about comparator?@Bimpelrekkie

Comment: @Neil_UK I explicitly mentioned **MOSFETs**. If the design were using BJTs I'd keep some of the BJTs in **active mode** (i.e. I would avoid saturation mode).